# How do get the volume of frequencies of a sound in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I'm having a problem, because I can't find anything online on how to get the volume of frequencies of a sound on a certain point of a wav file. I basically want to know, how to load a wav file (I can use node.js for that) and how to save the frequencies and the volume of a certain moment in an array.

[This is an eq, just to show you what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogebE.png)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Typically you do a _Fourier transform_ (or, more practically, a _Fast Fourier Transform_).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O3nm0Nvbi4

Comment: Was the intention for this to happen in the browser or server-side?

Comment: @Wyck thank you! The video really helped. Now, I need to figure out, how to save the frequencies from an individual moment in an array.

Comment: @fdcpp the main goal for it is to work in a browser, but I'm currently working server-side on it

Comment: If you choose exclusively the browser, you’ll have the whole WebAudio API at your fingertips, in which case there are a few existing questions that may be relevant. If they, closing the question would be best practice, if not, it would be good to add an edit as to why these questions don’t cover your case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502536/determining-frequencies-in-js-audiocontext-analysernode/44504975?r=SearchResults#44504975 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113580/simple-code-to-calculate-frequency-of-live-mic-audio-using-webaudio-api/23115743?r=SearchResults#23115743

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739888/playing-a-sound-in-a-browser-chrome-from-javascript?r=SearchResults